# JSLink Execute function on a column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Is it possible to execute a function on a column in file.Js ?

Example: `Suppliers` is my column name.

I want to execute a function

```
var lookupSample = lookupSample || {};

lookupSample.CustomizeFieldRendering = function() {
// Intialize the variables for overrides objects
var overrideCtx = {
    Templates: {
        Fields: {
            'Suppliers': {
                'NewForm': lookupSample.singleLookupValue
            },
        }
    }
};
overrideCtx.Templates.OnPostRender = PostRenderJs;


// Register the override of the field
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}

lookupSample.singleLookupValue = function(ctx) {
var output = [];
var field = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Choices;
output.push('<div class="ui-widget"> <select id="combobox">');
// Check if field contains data
if (field.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        output.push('<option id="');
        output.push(field[i].LookupId);
        output.push('">');
        output.push(field[i].LookupValue);
        output.push('</option>');
    }
    output.push('</select></div>');
}
// Push the value to the array
return output.join('');
}

function PostRenderJs (ctx){
    alert('Hello World');
}

lookupSample.CustomizeFieldRendering();
```

This code do what i want but it open 3 (cause i have 3 columns in my list, if i have 4 columns, that pop up 4 times, etc) alert with the same message.

And i want to pop this message only 1 time (based on my column `Suppliers`).

Something like

```
function PostRenderJs (ctx){
  if(ctx.columnname=="Suppliers"){
    alert('Hello World');
  }
};
```

So it would pop Hello World only 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code snippet :

If you want to execute some piece of code for specific field only, you can directly write your code for that specific field.

```
var options = {
      Templates: {
        Fields: {
          'Field1_Internal_Name': {
              View: /* function or string */,
              EditForm: /* function or string */,
              DisplayForm: /* function or string */,
              NewForm: /* function or string */
          },
        }
      },
    };
```

In refer above snippet,

1. replace "**Field1_Internal_Name**" with the internal name of your field
2. specify whether you are writting your code for View, EditForm, DisplayForm, NewForm
3. write your code.

Reference : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: I edited my post.

I just need to know how can i execute a function when a columnname = column